# Show text box based on drop down value provided

Tags: jquery

I have gone thru many post regarding show/hide text box on particular value in drop down. But I want this to happen for 10 rows and not only for one, can anyone please assist?

The below code which I have with me works only for 1 row.

Example:
There is a grid in which drop down and text box are placed. There are 10 rows in the grid. So as per the below code it works fine for first row. But if I want to do this for 6th row wherein drop down and text box are present; I need to hard core the coding lines. So I need to run a loop from 1 to 10 and check whether each drop down has particular value and onchange event trigger the textbox accordingly.

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    window.setInterval(function() {
      for (var k = 1; k < 11; k++) {
        var idx1 = 'Q13_' + k;
        var idx2 = 'Q14_' + k;
        var idx3 = 'Q15_' + k;
        $("input[name='+idx1+']").each(function() {
          $(this).attr("readonly", "true");
          $(this).css("background-color", "#DEDEDE");
        });

        $("input[name='+idx2+']").each(function() {
          $(this).attr("readonly", "true");
          $(this).css("background-color", "#DEDEDE");
        });

        $("input[name='+idx3+']").each(function() {
          $(this).attr("readonly", "true");
          $(this).css("background-color", "#DEDEDE");
        });

        var ccc = 'Q3_' + k;
        var r;
        $("input[name='+ccc+']").each(function() {;
          $(this).change(function() {;
            r = $(this).val();
            if (r != 2 || r != 5 || r != 8) {
              $("input[name='+idx1+']").attr("readonly", "false");;
              $("input[name='+idx1+']").css("background-color", "#000000");;
              $("input[name='+idx2+']").attr("readonly", "false");;
              $("input[name='+idx2+']").css("background-color", "#000000");;
              $("input[name='+idx3+']").attr("readonly", "false");;
              $("input[name='+idx3+']").css("background-color", "#000000");;
            }
          });
        });;

      }
    }, 200);;
  });;
</script>
```

Thanks,
Jigar

Comment: provide proper example for better understand .

Comment: You should add more details so that it is understood better by potential answerers

Comment: Guys, I am sorry for not clearing earlier.. I am updating above with example shortly..

Comment: Guys, I have updated the code what I have tried so far, can you please have a look?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function() {
     if ($("#yourDropDown").val() <= 10) {

         $("#yourTextBox").show();
     } else {

         $("#yourTextBox").hide();
     }
 });
```

Comment: I have added an example in my post.. I am unable to get code. Sorry.

Comment: I have updated the code above, can you please have a look @Tariq?